# Does Cartesian Product ever violate having the same property with its component sets?

Tags: general-topology

Let $A$ and $B$ be subsets of some set $X$. Let  $A$ , $B$ have some fixed property (compact, connected, finite, whatsoever) then $A\times B$ also have that property. Is there any case where this is not valid? i.e. $A$, $B$ have some property but $A\times B$ does not have it?

I think this is not possible, but I do not know how to prove it. Is it possible to prove, I am not sure. I have to define a what it means *to have a property* in mathematical terms. But what to do then, I could not find.

Comment: "not being a Cartesian product" is a property...

Comment: You're asking if there is a topological property $A$ such that $A$ and $B$ can have it but $A\times B$ does not have it. Right?

Comment: The property 'having two elements' is a counter-example, as is 'being a subset of $X$'...

Comment: @AsafKaragila Yes.

Comment: @yatima2975 "being a subset of $X$" isn't really a topological property in any good sense, though, since it's not homeomorphism-invariant.

Answer (score 4):

The [Sorgenfrey plane](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorgenfrey_plane) is not normal or Lindelöf despite the Sorgenfrey line having both of those properties. It's a rather useful counter-examples in topology.

Comment: In other words, normality and Lindelöf-ness are not preserved under products.

Answer (score 2):

There are several examples of such properties.

- We can make sense of the notion of "dimension" in a [purely topological way](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lebesgue_covering_dimension); then the product of two one-dimensional spaces won't in general be one-dimensional ($\mathbb{R}^2$ with the usual topology is two-dimensional, obviously).
- Along the same lines, note that $\mathbb{R}$ (with the usual topology) is connected, but becomes disconnected whenever you remove a single point. $\mathbb{R}^2$, however, remains connected after you remove one point (or indeed countably many points).
- Going into [more advanced territory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_topology), there are lots of other invariants besides dimension that we can assign to a topological space - homotopy groups, cohomology rings, ... And these invariants generally change wildly when we take Cartesian products. So e.g. "having homotopy group (isomorphic to) $\mathbb{Z}$" is a topological property which is not preserved under Cartesian products.
- If we bring set theory into the picture, things can get even more interesting: there are natural topological properties such that the usual axioms of set theory **cannot decide** whether they are preserved under Cartesian products! The countable chain condition (c.c.c.) is [an example of such a property](http://www.jstor.org/stable/43737128?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents).

Answer (score 1):

Some compactness-like properties are not preserved by even products of two spaces (which is why "plain" compactness is so beloved a property):

- a product of two pseudocompact spaces need not be pseudocompact.
- A product of two countably compact spaces need not be countably compact. (nicely enough, sequential compactness *is* preserved by finite or even countable products).
- A product of two Lindelöf or paracompact spaces need not be Lindelöf or paracompact. (the Michael line and variants can be used to show this, besides the classic Sorgenfrey plane, of course).
- There also are rather complex examples of the product of two [Baire](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baire_space) spaces that is not Baire.
- A product of two non-discrete orderable spaces is (almost?) never orderable.
- A product of two $T_0, T_1, T_2, T_3, T_{3\frac{1}{2}}$ spaces still has that same separation property. But this fails for $T_4, T_5, T_6$.

etc. etc.